# CONFUSING: same reputation points but different badges?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, migrated-questions

**It's very confusing** that reputation points is the same, but the badges are different on Stack Overflow and meta.

Can you make this clear, or change this feature?

Either reputation should be different or the badges should be the same!

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe, but quick explanation: On Meta, there is no reputation, so your Stack Overflow rep carries over. _However,_ you can still earn badges on Meta, so the badges you've earned here will be different from you main site badges.

Comment: "Shouting" is not a good way to handle downvotes. They don't affect your reputation, since there _isn't any_ on Meta. People likely feel this is something you really could have researched more first. One of the reasons to downvote is _"This question does not show any research effort..."_ (From the downvote tooltip.) The downvotes could also be from users disagreeing that it's confusing, as votes on Meta are often used to show (dis)agreement with a post or its premise.

Comment: and.... we are not "disliking". We are downvoting. Disliking is based on MY preferences..... downvoting has to do with quality. (on meta the two are related... but here I do think you are being downvoted for lack of research)

Answer (score 8):

The badges on Meta reflect participation on Meta, just the same as they reflect participation on the main site.

Main site reputation being the same as Meta was a convention from the rest of the network, and Stack Overflow was brought up to that convention.

Comment: Do note, this was recent (considering the age of SO). At first, MSO and MSE were one and the same.

Comment: @Braiam We're coming up on 3 years now.  It's not so recent anymore.